# PHP performance considerations of passing variable into a function

Tags: php, performance

Example code:

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    public $bar = array('a', 'b', 'c');
    public function getBar() {return $this->bar;}

    public function execute(array $fooArray) {
        foreach ($fooArray as $foo) {
            echo $foo.":".$this->checkBar($foo, $this->getBar())." ";// PASSED IN//
            //echo $foo.":".$this->checkBar($foo)." ";// RETRIEVED //
        }
    }

    // PASSED IN //
    public function checkBar($foo, array $fooCheck) {
        return in_array($foo, $fooCheck);
    }

    // RETRIEVED //
    /*public function checkBar($foo) {
         $fooCheck = $this->getBar();
         return in_array($foo, $fooCheck);
    }*/
}

$someClass = new MyClass();
$someClass->execute(array('a','f','c','g'));
?>
```

Are there any performance considerations to passing `$fooCheck` in as a variable into `checkBar` vs having `MyClass::checkBar()` handle calling the function itself?

Comment: Nope, it's all good.

Answer (score 2):

Having (1)

```
public function execute(array $fooArray)
{
    foreach ($fooArray as $foo) {
        echo $foo . ":" . $this->checkBar($foo, $this->getBar()) . " ";
    }
}

public function checkBar($foo, array $fooCheck)
{
    return in_array($foo, $fooCheck);
}
```

is **the exact same thing** (performance wise) as (2)

```
public function execute(array $fooArray)
{
    foreach ($fooArray as $foo) {
        echo $foo . ":" . $this->checkBar($foo) . " ";
    }
}

public function checkBar($foo)
{
    return in_array($foo, $this->getBar());
}
```

In example (1), if you needed `checkBar()` to handle several different array inputs, then you would be able to differentiate them in `execute()`. Whereas example (2) would be better if you knew you would only be checking against a single array.

It's easier to expand code that's written like example (1).